# How can I install Drupal 7.0 to Linux Mint

Tags: linux, installation, drupal

I read the document INSTALL.txt and it says that I should run the install script, point your browser to the base URL of your website. What command should I type to console to run the script?

And is the base URL of my website same as localhost as my project are under the directory /var/www ?

Comment: Why did you remove my answer as the correct one?  SLY's answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal 7 is a Web application; you don't install it as you would a MAKE file or a shell script.

What you need to do is make sure that Apache2, PHP5 (and GD for image processing), and MySQL are installed correctly.  I don't use Linux Mint, but I'm assuming it has `apt` so the following will work:

`sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server php5-mysql php5-gd`

Once that's done, you can follow the [instructions on Drupal's Website](http://drupal.org/documentation/install), but basically once Drupal has been extracted in your webroot and the correct permissions are set, you can just visit yourwebsite.com or your.linux.ip.address in your browser and the install/pre-requisites check will run automatically.

Note: you might want to go with 6.2 right now if you're interested in 3rd-party modules: from what I've seen, most of them haven't been updated to work with 7.0 yet or they're still in alpha form.

Comment: Ok. I managed to install Drupal and added me as a user. However, Drupal logged me in only once. After I quitted my job and tried to log in another time, it gave me an error message "Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?" I tried to request a new password but I didn't got a mail. What would cause such a problem?

Comment: you have to have given it the ability to send mail. You can configure php to do this (well php to use sendmail or something like that). Anyways you can reset the password through the MySQL database.